# restrict a user to download the app from google play if android version is older

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile

How to restrict a user to download the app from google play(google app store) if user's android version(SDK) is lower then a specific version. I am using Titanium to develop the app.

**Detail:** I have created an application for a client and it works fine with version 4.2.2 and above but there are some issues with 4.2.1 and below now client wants that if any user having version below 4.2.1 tries to download the app from app store, user get a message/notification about version.

I tried to set `minSdkVersion` in manifest file also setup the `default sdk version in properties to 4.2` but still all user can download and install the app. Is there any way to restrict user by downloading the app on the basis of android version.

I also added the property in `tiapp.xml`

```
 <android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <tool-api-level>8</tool-api-level>
        <manifest>
            <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4"/>
            <!--android:targetSdkVersion="7" -->
        </manifest>
    </android>
```

Here is the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.contingent.pcc" android:versionCode="4"
    android:versionName="1.2">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />

    <!-- TI_MANIFEST -->

    <application android:icon="@drawable/appicon"
        android:label="CNS PCC" android:name="CnsPccApplication"
        android:debuggable="false">

        <!-- TI_APPLICATION -->

        <activity android:name=".CnsPccActivity"
            android:label="CNS PCC" android:theme="@style/Theme.Titanium"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <!--<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />-->
                <data android:scheme="cnspcc" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
        <activity android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.TiTranslucentActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
        <activity android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.TiModalActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
        />
        <activity android:name="ti.modules.titanium.ui.TiTabActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
        <activity android:name="ti.modules.titanium.ui.android.TiPreferencesActivity" />

        <service android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.analytics.TiAnalyticsService"
            android:exported="false" />


    </application>

    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="false"/>  

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>           

</manifest>
```

Also check the properties:

[image]

Comment: @PankajKumar added plz check now

Comment: you are using minsdk version as 4. But it must be 17 for 4.2 So make a try with adding 17. This will not allow the user who have the OS version less that 4.2

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html details are here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using minsdk version as `4`. But it must be `17` for `4.2` So make a try with adding `17`. This will not allow the user who have the OS version less that `4`.

Read more details at [uses-sdk detail](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) and [Dashboards](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

If the user doesnot want to install the application if the android version is below 17.
Use the minium SDK version as 17.

```
          <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17" />
```

Comment: can you share some link with details that how `17==4.2`

Comment: Hi the api level of 4.2 is 17. you can clearly understand if you start to surf for api level for 2,2.3,3,4.2,etc like that.