# Restrict app to be downloadable from a specific version of android from google play store

Tags: android, google-play, restrict

I have tried with min-max version, but it does not work.

I also know that play store restricts specific device, but I want to restrict version of android not device.

i have tries this but isn`t work

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24994072/3221926

Answer (score 1):

You can set the API level in your AndroidManifest.xml, and limit it's minimum and maximum levels.

Specifically this line:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

That is set to be available for levels 14 - 19, which is *4.0 - 4.4*

You can read about it in more detail in the documentation:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Also here's the full  documentation on the manifest file:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

The Play store will detect which devices are available for those API levels and gives you the ability to ignore devices if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

specify

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

in your manifest file

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

This sets a specific API version version range which you want to restrict your app to be downloadable for specific Android version. Here only the users with API versions 14 to 19 can download your application.

Comment: i have tried but however app download in other version than specified in android:targetSdkVersion

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16536050/restrict-a-user-to-download-the-app-from-google-play-if-android-version-is-older?rq=1